# how do i find the mode of an array of integers

Tags: javascript, arrays

it is a scenario where a use inputs an array of integers and it returns the most frequent integer.

it is tested 3 times but will fail once, whether its the 1st 2nd or 3rd test.

```js
function arrayMode(array) {
  if (array.length === 0) {
    return null;
  }
  var sequence = {};
  var maxNo = array[3],
    maxCount = 3;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var Entry = array[i];
    if (sequence[Entry] === null)
      sequence[Entry] = -1;
    else
      sequence[Entry]++;
    if (sequence[Entry] > maxCount) {
      maxNo = Entry;
      maxCount = sequence[Entry];
    } else if (sequence[Entry] == maxCount) {
      maxNo += '&' + Entry;
      maxCount = sequence[Entry - 1];
    }
    return maxNo;
  }
}

console.log(arrayMode([1, 3, 3, 3, 1])) // output = 3
console.log(arrayMode([1, 2, 3, 1, 1])) // output = 1
console.log(arrayMode([2, 2, 2, 1])) // output = 2
```

Comment: Could you please explain in plain english what that code is supposed to do? There are some parts (`=== null`, `-1`, `maxNo += '&' + Entry` ...) that make little sense to me.

Comment: It looks like the intent is to return the number which occurs most frequently in the input array (though the code isn't working currently of course).  @LAnga  I've updated the snippet to include your sample input; please check to make sure I haven't misinterpreted what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @MarkMeyer That was my error in editing the question :(  Correcting now

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several mistakes, if you find an entry not seen previously you set the `sequence` for that entry to `-1`, why not `1`? 
And you initialize `maxNo` to `array[3]` and `maxCount` to `3`, why?

Does this make more sense to you?

```
function arrayMode(arr)
{
    var mode = null;
    var frequencies = [];
    var maxFrequency = 0;
    for (var i in arr)
    {
        var value = arr[i];

        // if we haven't seen this value before, init its frequency to 0
        if (frequencies[value]===undefined) frequencies[value] = 0;

        // increase this value's frequency
        frequencies[value]++;

        // if this value's frequency is bigger than the max we've seen
        // so far, this value is now the new mode.
        if (frequencies[value] > maxFrequency)
        {
            maxFrequency = frequencies[value];
            mode = value;
        }
    }
    return mode;
}
```

If you want to return *all* modi in case there are more than one entries with the max number of frequencies (for example if for `[1,1,2,3,3]` you want the mode to be `1 & 3`) then you can do so by a simple extra loop at the end.